# Push rejected : No JIRA Issue found in commit message.branch name (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to http://@bitbucket.com

Tags: git, bitbucket, jira

I am trying to push my commit to bitbucket, getting an error Push Rejected No JIRA Issue found in commit message.

I had modified the commit message to match the Jira ticket but still getting the same error:

```
remote:
remote:remote: Push rejected.
remote:
remote: refs/heads/feature/JR-2923: df323hfsdfw3u23u : No JIRA Issue found in commit message.
remote:
To http://bitbucket/repo/name
 ! [remote rejected] feature/JR-2923 -> feature/JR-2923 (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://user@http://bitbucket/repo/name'
```

Comment: How did you modify the commit message? Who controls the pre-receive script on your Bitbucket Server instance?

Comment: to modify the commit message I use git commit --amend and modify in the vi editor.

Answer (score 1):

I added double quotes to my message and it worked.
git commit -m "your message about the issue"

Answer (score 0):

You had similar issues reported like (assuming you are using [YACC / yet-another-commit-checker](https://github.com/sford/yet-another-commit-checker)):

- [issue 132](https://github.com/sford/yet-another-commit-checker/issues/132): check your regex, and also your authentication

On the regex side, for instance:

> Actually, I think the issue might be the use of groups in the commit message regex.
>   if I change:
>
> ```
> ^[([A-Z]+)-(\d+)](.|\n)+
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> ^([[A-Z]+-\d+])(.|\n)+
> ```
>
> Then the group is now ([PROJNAME-1234]) instead of [(PROJNAME)-(1234)].

And on the authentication side:

> If the issue really exists and JQL `issueKey=CM-933` works when you manually test it, then this *feels* like a permission issue, because if the user doesn't have permission to view it, you would see empty results and YACC complaining it can't find the issue.
>
> In a typical setup, communication looks like:
>
> ```
> browser <--\        browser <--\
>            |                   |
> git <----> BBS <-- oauth --> JIRA
> ```
>
> As per your comments, you manually verified and tested BBS and JIRA when logging into them in a browser.
>   I would also spot check that the expected users are being used when git connects to BBS, and also the BBS<->JIRA communication which should probably be using oauth.
>   If it isn't using oauth, that might also explain what is going on, because it might be using a user other than the one you expect when communicating with JIRA.

- [issue 148](https://github.com/sford/yet-another-commit-checker/issues/148): check if the plugin is activated

That is:

> Upgrading BBS may automatically disable plugins, which may require you to re-enable plugins.
>   In YACC's case, the Configure button should be displayed again after enabling YACC in UPM.